# What's the Role of CACHE_ID and CACHE_TAG in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache

In Model Classes, I have seen this constant, **CACHE_ID** and **CACHE_TAG**, I know it is used to store data in the cache.

But *how does it actually work*. What *should be considered while caching and flushing our custom variables?*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cache id is used to identify a specific cache record.
If you save something in the cache you can later retrieve it by its id.
Cache tags are a way to assign labels to different cache records so you can later clear multiple cache entries based on those labels (tags).

For example, let's say you want to cache a category view page.
This will have as tags `category_{id of category here}`.
But the category page contains products. SO maybe you want to also add the tags `product_{id of each product here}`.

Now, when you change a product and/or a category you need to clean the cache for each entity involved.
So when you update a product you clear all cache entries with the tag `product_{id of product here}`.
This way, the category page cache I mentioned above will get cleared also.